# Accessing the values in a list in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I have got this code in PyQGIS to to save a selected feature into a variable.

```
class selectTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):
    
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, self.canvas, self.layer)
        self.iface.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.active_changed)
        
    def active_changed(self, layer):
        self.layer.removeSelection()
        if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer) and layer.isSpatial():
            self.layer = layer
            self.setLayer(self.layer)
            
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        found_feature = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.LayerSelection)
        self.layer.selectByIds([f.mFeature.id() for f in found_feature])
        
        print (type(found_feature))
        print (found_feature)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.layer.removeSelection()

t = selectTool(iface)
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

This is working so far. Just the `print` statement... `print (found_feature)` ... gives me:

```
[<qgis._gui.QgsMapToolIdentify.IdentifyResult object at 0x000001E2669BDDC8>]
```

My question is now: how can I print the features and values which are inside the created list? I guess I somehow have to make it accessible?

I am very new to PyQGIS and also Python.

Comment: The list has one item. That means you clicked on one feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, since you clicked on one feature, the list has one item. In any case, `found_feature` gives all [`IdentifyResult` instances](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/Map/QgsMapToolIdentify.html#qgis.gui.QgsMapToolIdentify.IdentifyResult) and `IdentifyResult.mFeature` gives the feature.

If you want to print all features and attributes, change `canvasPressEvent` like this:

```
def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
    found_feature = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.LayerSelection)
    self.layer.selectByIds([f.mFeature.id() for f in found_feature])
    
    identified_features = [f.mFeature for f in found_feature]
     
    for f in identified_features:
        print(f.id())
        print(f.attributes())
```